# How to change DNS to an amazon-EC2 instance

Tags: amazon-ec2, dns

I have a Cluster Compute instance on amazon-EC2. Clusters are located in US (zone 1), therefore the public IP address is from there. Unfortunately some websites that I need to get access to are not accessible, since they recognized that the IP address is from US. If I change DNS servers from inside the instaces (as you can usually do on pc), it doesn't work, because it is a matter of the inside network linked to the instance (I guess).
I heard about the Route 53 system, but I did not understand if it could work out for me or not. Is there anyone that can help me?

Comment: Not sure what you're asking, but have you looked into Elastic IPs?  http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/using-instance-addressing.html  Elastic IPs are AWS's way of providing public IP addresses to your instances.

Answer (score 1):

A few ways I can think of doing it.

1. Host your cluster in a different AZ
2. Use a VPN service such as StrongVPN
3. Use a proxy server that's located outside the US.

Using DNS isn't going to help you as the dns name will be attached to your instance and it will always have the same ip as your instance. Changing the DNS name does not change the fact that your server is located in the US.

Amazon also offers a VPN service if you have servers with another provider outside the US you can directly connect the cluster to your non US network and thus you inherit the IP of the other network.